# How to target a class after using addClass()?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to code a very simple chess board. The idea is just to have the pieces and to be able to move them around.

To do so, I was adding a 'selected' class when clicking it and I then wanted to move the piece with the 'selected' class to the square clicked.

But targeting '.selected' is not working. It works if I add it manually, but it doesn't work if I'm using addClass to do it. Any ideas on how to do this?

```js
$('.board').on('click', '.circle', function() {
  $('.circle').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
})


var $movingpiece = $('.selected');

$('.square').on('click', function() {
  $movingpiece.appendTo($(this));
});
```

Comment: You're setting `$movingpiece` before the code in either function is called.

Comment: A little more information will be needed to answer this question.

Comment: Hi @mafalda Correa, Please paste your html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define .selected inside the context of the function not outside, this should work;

```js
$('.board').on('click', '.circle', function() {
  $('.circle').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
})

$('.square').on('click', function() {
  $('.selected').eq(0).appendTo($(this));
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did work! I did suppose the solution would be as simple as that, but I couldn't work out what wasn't working.

Comment: According to @HereticMonkey, "You're setting $movingpiece before the code in either function is called" movingpiece should be defined inside the function. Do accept this answer if it worked. :D Thanks